# How to check if there is a collider(gameobject) on the position or not

Tags: unity-game-engine, dynamic, position, gameobject, collider

I have a tic tac toe game , and I want to make it dynamical, so I need some collider checking function or method, but I cannot find it in internet, so I am asking here. unity

I have this code for making my tic tac toe dynamic , it is not finished yet.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform Button;
public int rows;
public int columns;

void Start () {

    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

        Transform newButton = Instantiate<Transform> (Button);
        newButton.SetParent(GameObject.Find ("ButtonsContainer").transform);
        newButton.localScale = Vector3.one;
        newButton.localPosition = new Vector3(x,y,0);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish. [onCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) can be used to detect collisions.

Comment: I am trying to make loop,  at the start of the game, it will take number of rows and columns that would be given from user. and will check if there is a collider on that position. for example . I give 2 rows, it will check 1 * 150 position then 2 * 150 position if there is no collider on second position it should make button

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you determine if a collider is in a certain position, one would be to have a seperate collider object that you move to the position and then do the collision checking on that object using [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

While you can achieve your goal this way, I would recommend that you take a different approach to determine where the colliders are. if this is tic tac toe then it's based on a grid, you could store all of the games data within a [2D array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) and then you would always know the position of the objects without having to scan the scene for them. Not only would this be more efficient but it would also make dealing with the rule checking much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect colliders by code is to use [Physics.SphereCast method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html).